# Why is this augmented 4th bad ? 16th century counterpoint

Tags: theory, harmony, counterpoint

[image]

I'm studying 16th century counterpoint.

My book says, when writing a melody for second species, augmented 4th or augmented 5th shouldn't occur between strong beat and a strong beat.

But this is not between the strong beats isn't it ?
It's past the strong beats so I assume it's fine but why is it saying this is a bad example ?

Comment: The issue here is that the consecutive scale fragment spans a augmented 4th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the consecutive scale fragment spans a augmented 4th. It forms what is called a *compound tritone*, and many counterpoint textbooks advise against it, as in the section below, of Schoenberg's *Preliminary Exercises in Counterpoint*, p. 6:

[image]

In other words, even if the interval of a tritone is 'filled' with the notes between the 4th and the 7th, it is still to be avoided. In your example, if the note following the F were and E, there would be no problem, as the interval between the ends of the scale fragment would have been a perfect fifth.